# MongoDB: Usin Project with multiple pipelines

Tags: python, mongodb

I have two differents pipelines comming from this:

```
command_12 = {"$facet": {"q1": my_query_1, "q2": my_query_2}}
    my_query.append(command_12)
```

And when I tried to project:

```
command_16 = {"$project": {
                                "_id": "$q2.hours",
                                "total_measurements":"$q2.total_measurements" ,
                                "zero_bikes_measurements": "$q1.zero_bikes_measurements"

                                }
                 }
    my_query.append(command_16)
```

My result is:

```
_id  :  ['14', '23', '15', '10', '04', '02', '18', '19', '00', '06', '09', '03', '01', '07', '05', '11', '13', '17', '20', '21', '08', '12', '16', '22']
total_measurements  :  [284, 284, 284, 283, 284, 284, 284, 283, 284, 283, 282, 284, 284, 284, 280, 282, 284, 284, 284, 284, 284, 284, 284, 284]
zero_bikes_measurements  :  [181, 179, 159, 151, 138, 120, 55, 19, 7, 9, 12, 17, 36, 35, 47, 54, 81, 148, 179, 185, 174, 184, 162, 161]
```

But I'm trying to get a collection with individual elements like:

```
_id: 14
total_measurements:284
zero_bikes_measurements:181
```

I tried to unwind but it create multiple documents repeating values.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      mix: {
        $map: {
          input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$id" } ] },
          as: "s",
          in: {
            id: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$id", "$$s" ] },
            total_measurements: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$total_measurements", "$$s" ] },
            zero_bikes_measurements: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$zero_bikes_measurements", "$$s" ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$mix"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$mix"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4LnSABNY7L2)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      zip: {
        $zip: {
          inputs: [ "$id", "$total_measurements", "$zero_bikes_measurements" ],
          useLongestLength: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$zip"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$zip", 0 ] },
      total_measurements: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$zip", 1 ] },
      zero_bikes_measurements: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$zip", 2 ] }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6K6Fs3cOPO2)

Comment: Coool learn something new 